# Ruby remove new line character between html tags.

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, find

I would like to remove all the new line characters between

```
<div class="some class"> arbitrary amount of text here with possible new line characters </div>
```

Is this possible in ruby?

Comment: I wonder why you do want to do that, since new line aren't show on a webpage? What do you try to archive?

Comment: I'm trying to build a small app that displays all my Facebook posts on a certain topic. The Facebook archive is full of line breaks that I'd like to get rid of for the experience of doing so, and so I can view and act on the data more confidently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do this using the Nokogiri gem.  For example:

```
require "rubygems"
require "nokogiri"

html = %q!
<div class="some class">      arbitrary amount of text
here with possible
new line
characters        </div>
!


doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)
div = doc.at('div')
div.inner_html = div.inner_html.gsub(/[\n\r]/, " ").strip

puts html
puts '-' * 60
puts doc.to_s
```

When run will output this:

```
<div class="some class">      arbitrary amount of text
here with possible
new line
characters        </div>
------------------------------------------------------------

<div class="some class">arbitrary amount of text  here with possible  new line  characters</div>
```